Pandas Merging on Nearest Date with Consideration for Grouping
I am developing a python solution to a data transformation challenge and am experiencing a small hurdle that I can't seem to figure out. I want to merge the two data frames (i.e., df1 & df2) to create a new data frame that has inserted df2['value2'] into df1['value1'] while considering date and 'Type' alignment. Has anyone ever solved a similar problem? Is pandas the best library for solving this problem?
Please see the code snippet I am using in my jupyter notebook for solution testing below.
import pandas as pd 

df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'Type': ['Labor', 'Material', 'Labor', 'Material' , 'Labor', 'Material', 'Labor', 'Material'],'date1': ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-03-01', '2021-03-01', '2021-04-01', '2021-04-01'], 'value1': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'Type': ['Labor', 'Material', 'Labor', 'Material'],'date2': ['2021-01- 
11', '2021-02-22', '2021-02-05', '2021-03-15'], 'value2': [10,20,25,45]})

display(df1)
display(df2)

df1['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date1'])
df2['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date2'])

df1 = df1.sort_values(['date1', 'Type'])
df2 = df2.sort_values(['date2', 'Type'])

merge_df = pd.merge_asof(df2, df1, left_on= 'date2', right_on= 'date1' , by = 'Type', 
direction = 'nearest')

display(merge_df)

The output I am trying to achieve is visualized below.



Type
Date
Value




Labor
2021-01-01
10


Material
2021-01-01
0


Labor
2021-02-01
25


Material
2021-02-01
20


Labor
2021-03-01
0


Material
2021-03-01
45


Labor
2021-04-01
0


Material
2021-04-01
0




I think its not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve. could you share the structure of the expected output dataframe please.

I edited the question to include the expected output dataframe.

What if you have two observations in a month?

The values in the output are unclear, could you please explain where each 0 is coming from?

I apologize! I caught an error. I adjusted my df1 to better represent the data frame I am trying to merge on. My goal is to represent the sum of the two observations in a given month from df2 and align the sum to the nearest date in df1 @ifly6.

@mozway, the 0s in df1 can just be null data.

@BP130 OK, I got it, you need to invert df1/df2 and to merge by month as well. See my updated answer

merge_asof is a left merge, you need to use df1 on the left. Also you have to use the month as by:
out = (pd.merge_asof(df1.assign(month=df1['date1'].dt.to_period('M')),
                     df2.assign(month=df2['date2'].dt.to_period('M')),
                     left_on='date1', right_on='date2',
                     by=['Type', 'month'], direction='nearest')
         .fillna({'value2': 0})
      )

Output:
       Type      date1  value1    month      date2  value2
0     Labor 2021-01-01       0  2021-01 2021-01-11    10.0
1  Material 2021-01-01       0  2021-01        NaT     0.0
2     Labor 2021-02-01       0  2021-02 2021-02-05    25.0
3  Material 2021-02-01       0  2021-02 2021-02-22    20.0
4     Labor 2021-03-01       0  2021-03        NaT     0.0
5  Material 2021-03-01       0  2021-03 2021-03-15    45.0
6     Labor 2021-04-01       0  2021-04        NaT     0.0
7  Material 2021-04-01       0  2021-04        NaT     0.0

Intermediates:
# df1.assign(month=df1['date1'].dt.to_period('M'))
       Type      date1  value1    month
0     Labor 2021-01-01       0  2021-01
1  Material 2021-01-01       0  2021-01
2     Labor 2021-02-01       0  2021-02
3  Material 2021-02-01       0  2021-02
4     Labor 2021-03-01       0  2021-03
5  Material 2021-03-01       0  2021-03
6     Labor 2021-04-01       0  2021-04
7  Material 2021-04-01       0  2021-04

# df2.assign(month=df2['date2'].dt.to_period('M'))
       Type      date2  value2    month
0     Labor 2021-01-11      10  2021-01
2     Labor 2021-02-05      25  2021-02
1  Material 2021-02-22      20  2021-02
3  Material 2021-03-15      45  2021-03


awesome stuff! This worked perfectly! Can you explain a bit more why/how you used the assign function?

@BP130 it adds one column in each dataframe with the monthly period to use as secondary by key. See the updated answer with intermediates

Use : from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree. it is very efficient and fast for Huge complex datasets.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree

# Sample data with many columns
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Type': ['Labor', 'Material', 'Labor', 'Material', 'Labor', 'Material', 'Labor', 'Material'],
    'date1': ['1990-01-01', '1990-01-01', '1990-02-01', '1990-02-01', '1990-03-01', '1990-03-01', '1990-04-01', '1990-04-01'],
    'value1': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Type': ['Labor', 'Material', 'Labor', 'Material'],
    'date2': ['1990-01-11', '1990-02-22', '1990-02-05', '1990-03-15'],
    'value2': [10, 20, 25, 45]
})

# Convert dates to datetime
df1['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date1'])
df2['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date2'])

# Convert dates to timestamps (seconds since epoch)
df1['date1_ts'] = df1['date1'].astype(np.int64) // 10**9
df2['date2_ts'] = df2['date2'].astype(np.int64) // 10**9

# Build BallTree with df1 dates
tree = BallTree(df1[['date1_ts']].values)
dist,idx = tree.query(X = df2[['date2_ts']], k =1 )

df2['nearest_index'] = idx.flatten()
'''
print(df2)
      Type      date2  value2   date2_ts  nearest_index
0     Labor 1990-01-11      10  632016000              0
1  Material 1990-02-22      20  635644800              4
2     Labor 1990-02-05      25  634176000              2
3  Material 1990-03-15      45  637459200              4
'''
closest_matches = df1.iloc[df2['nearest_index']]
'''
closest_matches :
    Type      date1  value1   date1_ts
0  Labor 1990-01-01       0  631152000
4  Labor 1990-03-01       0  636249600
2  Labor 1990-02-01       0  633830400
4  Labor 1990-03-01       0  636249600
'''
res = df2.join(
closest_matches.reset_index(drop=True), rsuffix = '_nearest'   
)

print(res.to_string())

'''
       Type      date2  value2   date2_ts  nearest_index  Type_nearest    date1   value1   date1_ts
0     Labor 1990-01-11      10  632016000              0        Labor 1990-01-01       0  631152000
1  Material 1990-02-22      20  635644800              4        Labor 1990-03-01       0  636249600
2     Labor 1990-02-05      25  634176000              2        Labor 1990-02-01       0  633830400
3  Material 1990-03-15      45  637459200              4        Labor 1990-03-01       0  636249600
'''
res['month'] = res['date1'].dt.to_period('M').astype(str)
res = res.drop(columns=['nearest_index','date1_ts','date2_ts','Type_nearest'])
res = res[['Type','month','date1', 'value1', 'date2', 'value2']]
print(res.to_string())
'''
      Type    month      date1  value1      date2  value2
0     Labor  1990-01 1990-01-01       0 1990-01-11      10
1  Material  1990-03 1990-03-01       0 1990-02-22      20
2     Labor  1990-02 1990-02-01       0 1990-02-05      25
3  Material  1990-03 1990-03-01       0 1990-03-15      45
'''

